# GDM lock screen after resume

Tags: gnome, suspend, gdm, sleep

I saw a really old question a but like this one but with no answer and no activity in three years.

I'm on arch linux with GDM and gnome and when I resume my laptop from suspend, the screen is on what I was doing previously (like web browser), then it goes black and I need to hit a key to show password prompt of gdm.

It's annoying for two reasons, its slow to process to thoses steps and its also a security flaw to be able to see the screen on resume.

I tested lighdtm but of course no password since gnome activate it only for gdm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequent bug in Ubuntu as well, which uses gdm and GNOME.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364813/after-suspend-on-resume-ubuntu-briefly-shows-content-of-session-before-display/1364820#1364820

Give or take- there is no solution I know of yet.